# Problem of values in a $3\times3$ magic square

Tags: matrices, arithmetic, integers, magic-square

We give the following integers :
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
-2 & x_2 & x_1 \\
17 & -8 & 9 \\
3 & x_3 & x_4
\end{matrix}\right]$$

The magic constant is equal to $18$ then I found two possibilities for the four unknown integers. The first weird thing is the fact that $-8$ is at the center of the square... What value do I have to change to get only one solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are your two different solutions?  I only get 1.

Comment: @kimchilover you'll get two solutions because it depends of the diagonal you chose. The two diagonals are necessarily different.

Comment: Here is what to do if you want the two diagonals to be *magic* as well.  Since we know that, with the current table, it is not possible, we want to change exactly one filled entry.  The only entry that can be changed is $17$, and we have to change it to $-25$.  Then there exists exactly one solution: $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(-19,-3,-13,-14)\,.$$

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks, I see ! Now the constant to $(-24)$ right ?

Comment: Yes, and I also added another comment under Jean-Claude's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are how we can readjust the table to make it a complete magic square.  That is, both diagonals are also *magic* (namely, each diagonal sum equals the *magic constant*, which is the sum of each row or each column).  The current magic constant is $18$.

---

**Approach I: Only one previously filled entry can be changed.**

Clearly, the magic constant cannot be kept at $18$.  Suppose that the new magic constant is $M$.  If the entry $17$ is untouched, then either the first column or the second row will still sum to $18\neq M$.  Therefore, $17$ has to be changed, and it will become $M-1$.

With this change, we get $x_1=M+5$ by looking at the diagonal containing $x_1$.  Similarly, $x_4=M+10$ from the diagonal containing $x_4$.  The third column dictates that $x_1+9+x_4=M$, which then mean that $$(M+5)+9+(M+10)=M\,.$$  Thus, $M=-24$.  Hence, we obtain $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(-19,-3,-13,-14)\,,$$ and the entry $17$ is now changed to $-25$.  Therefore, the table is now
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
-2&-3&-19
\\
\hline
-25&-8&9\\
\hline
3&-13&-14
\\
\hline
\end{array}\,.$$

---

**Approach II: Only two previously filled entries can be changed.**

We now want to also keep the magic constant at $18$.  Note that the entry $17$ cannot be touched, otherwise at least one other entry in the first column and one other entry in the second row will need to change.

If $-8$ is untouched, then $9$ is also untouched.  Hence, $-2$ and $3$ will be readjusted.  Suppose that $-2$ is changed to $t$.  Thus, $3$ becomes $1-t$.  Using the two diagonals, we obtain $x_1=t+25$ and $x_4=26-t$.  Nonetheless, the sum of the third column is now $$x_1+9+x_4=(t+25)+9+(26-t)=60\neq 18\,.$$ Therefore, $-8$ has to be changed.

Suppose that $-8$ is changed to $k$.  Then $9$ becomes $1-k$.  By dealing with the diagonals, we get $x_1=15-k$ and $x_4=20-k$.  Thus, the condition on the third column requires that
$$18=x_1+(1-k)+x_4=(15-k)+(1-k)+(20-k)=36-3k\,,$$
or $k=6$.  Ergo, $8$ and $9$ will now be $6$ and $-5$, respectively.  Then, we get
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(9,11,1,14)\,.$$
Therefore, the table is now
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
-2&11&9
\\
\hline
17&6&-5\\
\hline
3&1&14
\\
\hline
\end{array}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks for answering !

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x_1$ is known. Then:

- first row: $x_2=20-x_1$,
- second column: $x_3=26-x_2=6+x_1$,
- third column: $x_4=9-x_1$.

And we can check the last row: $3+x_3+x_4=3+6+x_1+9-x_1=18$. *(actually this check is not necessary, since the sum of the whole square is $3\times18$ (by construction of columns) and the two first rows do sum to $18$.)*

So, for any integer $x_1$, you get a magic square. There are infinitely many solutions.

If you want the diagonals to sum to $18$ too, then necessarily $x_1=23$ and $x_4=9-x_1=-14$. But then $-2-8+x_4\ne 18$, so there is no solution with "magic diagonals". There are two solutions however if you allow only one magic diagonal: either $x_1=23$ or $x_4=28$.

---

To be able to get a full magic square, with both diagonals, we need to change at least one of the known values, and actually more to keep the magic constant. Let's try:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
-2 & x_2 & x_1 \\
17+a & -8 & 9-a \\
3-a & x_3 & x_4
\end{matrix}\right]$$

The we have the same values for $x_2$ and $x_3$ as a function of $x_1$, and $x_4=9+a-x_1$.

Since with haven't changed the diagonals, we still need $x_1=23$, thus $x_4=a-14$. So for $a=32$, we get:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
-2 & -3 & 23 \\
49 & -8 & -23 \\
-29 & 29 & 18
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: Indeed I agree, but what do I have to change to obtain "magic diagonals" ?

Comment: @Maman I updated the answer. You need obviously to change the known values. Here is a solution, though not very interesting due to the opposite values. Batominovski's answer above is better if you don't want to keep the magic constant.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  I figured out how to make both diagonals *magic* as well as keeping the magic constant at $18$ by changing exactly two filled entries (changing just one entry is of course not possible).  The only way to do this is to change $-8$ to $6$, and $9$ to $-5$.  Then, the only solution is $$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(9,11,1,14)\,.$$

Comment: @Batominovski Nice!

Comment: @Batominovski Well done ! How did you get the idea ?

Comment: Maybe I will write what I did tomorrow. It's late now (~2AM), and I want to sleep soon.

Comment: @Batominovski No problem ! I know that $6$ is divided by $3$ and the center of the square is most of the time divided by $3$...

Answer (score 0):

I found a sort of magic solution $$-2,39,-19\\17,-8,9\\3,-13,28$$

It is fine except for one diagonal.

How did you find two solutions.

Comment: If you start with the second diagonal, you will find that $x_1=+23$.